# apt-get update returning error

Tags: apt

Whenever I try to do `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get upgrade`, this is what is returned:

`invalid section len 536870958, max remaining 46`

Any ideas what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: I think that has to do with filesystem block sizes but I'm not certain.

Comment: Provide the exact output.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the same issue I had yesterday, apt -get is supposedly now a legacy command. Get rid of the "-get" portion of the command and the command should work. I needed it to initially update my 2 day old install so that I could install Ice Weasel because Chromium was constantly locking up my spanky new Pi3.

EDIT: Used "apt" instead of the "apt -get" command to install Kodi today as well. Worked first try even though the instructions said to use "apt -get".